# show component error in mat-from-field angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

i want to create a share component for show error in angular material .

this is my share component `pfa-share-error`:

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="fieldErrors(fieldName).required && fieldErrors(fieldName)">
        Reqierd
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error  *ngIf="fieldErrors(fieldName).touched && fieldErrors(fieldName)">
       Reqierd
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="fieldErrors(fieldName).pattern && fieldErrors(fieldName)">
        Reqierd
  </mat-error>
```

and i using this in the my form :

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>{{ "COUNTEY.NAME" | translate }}</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="name" matInput />
    <pfa-share-error [form]="addCountryFG" field="name"></pfa-share-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

but it show like this in my form when error occure : [image: Demo]

i want show that like this :

[image: Demo]

**now how can i solve this problem ????**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like following:

In your main HTML file:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>{{ "COUNTEY.NAME" | translate }}</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="name" matInput />
    <mat-error>
       <pfa-share-error [form]="addCountryFG" field="name"></pfa-share-error>
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your shared component `pfa-share-error`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="fieldErrors(fieldName).required && fieldErrors(fieldName)">
    This field is required and cannot be empty
</ng-container>
```